# Multiprocess : Persistent Pool?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool, persistent

I have code like the one below :

```
def expensive(self,c,v):
    .....

def inner_loop(self,c,collector):
    self.db.query('SELECT ...',(c,))
    for v in self.db.cursor.fetchall() :
        collector.append( self.expensive(c,v) ) 

def method(self):

    # create a Pool
    #join the Pool ??

    self.db.query('SELECT ...')
    for c in self.db.cursor.fetchall() :
        collector = []

        #RUN the whole cycle in parallel in separate processes
        self.inner_loop(c, collector)

        #do stuff with the collector

    #! close the pool ?
```

both the Outer and the Inner loop are thousands of steps ...
I think I understand how to run a Pool of couple of processes.
All the examples I found show that more or less.

But in my case I need to lunch a persistent Pool and then feed the data (c-value). Once a inner-loop process has finished I have to supply the next-available-c-value.
And keep the processes running and collect the results.

How do I do that ?

---

A clunky idea I have is :

```
def method(self):
 ws = 4
 with Pool(processes=ws) as pool :
     cs = []
     for i,c in enumerate(..) :
       cs.append(c)  
       if i % ws == 0 :
         res = [pool.apply(self.inner_loop, (c)) for i in range(ws)]
         cs = []
         collector.append(res)
```

will this keep the same pool running !! i.e. not lunch new process every time ?i

---

Do I need  'if i % ws == 0' part or I can use imap(), map_async() and the Pool obj will block the loop when available workers are exhausted and continue when some are freed ?

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers already?  If so, can you elaborate a bit more on what you've confused about in particular?

Comment: my main confusion is how u partition N-c-values and keep N-processes fed. The for loop also has to feed N values at a time but it generates ONE at a time

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the way that [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) works is:

> Worker processes within a Pool typically live for the complete duration of the Pool’s work queue.

So simply submitting all your work to the pool via `imap` should be sufficient:

```py
with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    initial_results = db.fetchall("SELECT c FROM outer")
    results = [pool.imap(self.inner_loop, (c,)) for c in initial_results]
```

That said, if you really are doing this to fetch things from the DB, it *may* make more sense to move more processing down into that layer (bring the computation to the data rather than bringing the data to the computation).

Comment: i do that thanks.. in my case partitioning the big query and precaching the initial batch and using the pool made my job finish in 1hour compared to 5++ hours ;)